# How to get accuracy and f1-score from each fold in GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm using the GridSearchCV object to train a classifier. I setup 5-fold validation parameter search and after calling fit(), I need to see the metrics for each fold's validation set, namely accuracy and f1-score. How can I do this?

```
 clf = GridSearchCV(pipeline,
                        param_grid=param_grid, 
                        n_jobs=1, 
                        cv=5,
                        compute_training_score=True)
```

Note:

- I don't have a separate testing set to use so I can't just take the result of predict and do it with the standard metrics functions.
- using the clf.best_scores_ doesn't give the information I want, only the mean_validation_score and its standard deviation.

Comment: I don't see `compute_training_score` in the documentation , is it still a valid parameter?

Answer (score 1):

Scores are located in `grid_scores_`, in particular in `cv_validation_scores`:

> **grid_scores_** : list of named tuples
>
> Contains scores for all parameter
>   combinations in param_grid. Each entry corresponds to one parameter
>   setting. Each named tuple has the attributes:
>
> - parameters, a dict of
>     parameter settings
> - mean_validation_score, the mean score over the
>     cross-validation folds
> - cv_validation_scores, the list of scores for
>     each fold

However you will not get two metrics. The whole point of such optimizers is to maximize some single metric/scorer function, thus only this thing is stored inside of an object. In order to get such, you will need to run it twice, each time with different score function.

Comment: what is each validation_score, is the default score defined as something particular?

Comment: by default it is accuracy

Comment: thanks @Lejlot, how can I switch that to mean average precision or something else?

Comment: read the docs for GridSearchCV, there is a `scoring` parameter