# How to get F1 Score and Accuracy for every model tried with GridSearchCV?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to get the `F1 score` and `accuracy` for each model trained with my SVM, so for every set of parameters tried with `GridSearchCV`. I might have found how to do so for `accuracy`, but I have no idea how to do this for `F1 Score`.

For example, I'd like the F1 for kernel `linear`, and `c=1e-3`. Then F1 again for `linear and C=1e-1`, and finally F1 score for `linear and C=1` and `C=10`. How?

Here is a bit of my code that is relevant:

```
parameters = {'kernel':['linear'], 'C':[1e-3, 1e-1, 1, 10]}

svc = svm.SVC(cache_size=2048)
cv = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits=5, test_size=0.2, random_state=42)
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, cv=cv, n_jobs=8)
grid_result = clf.fit(X_train, y_train)
grid_result.cv_results_
my_dict = defaultdict(partial(np.ndarray, 0))
my_dict['params'] = grid_result.cv_results_['params']
my_dict['mean_valid_score'] = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_test_score'] # accuracy for valid dataset
my_dict['mean_train_score'] = grid_result.cv_results_['mean_train_score'] # accuracy for train
```

I read the [GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html#sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV) documentation, but I can't find anything that does what I need.

I found `cv_results_`, which gives a couple of information, like `mean_valid_score` and `mean_train_score` seems to be giving me the `accuracy` score for every model tried if I understand correctly. But F1 isn't there.

There is also [scoring](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#scoring-parameter) that seems interesting, maybe it does what I want? But I can't understand how to use it for my problem, and how to actually get the scores for each model tried.

I also found on some forums `grid_scores_`, like this [SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36461289/how-to-get-accuracy-and-f1-score-from-each-fold-in-gridsearchcv) but it seems to be [deprecated](https://www.quora.com/How-do-I-find-out-the-model-produced-by-a-GridSearchCV-for-any-fold-produced-by-cross_val_score/answer/Manoj-Kumar-23) now, and I can't find anything about this in the documentation as of now? How do we use it?

I want to do something like [this](https://blancas.io/sklearn-evaluation/user_guide/grid_search.html), but for different measures: accuracy and f1!

Comment: @Scratch'N'Purr Did you actually read my post? I took the time to write about `scoring`. I even included the same link you just sent...

Answer (score 3):

If you try

```
clf = GridSearchCV(svc, parameters, scoring = ['f1','accuracy'], cv=cv, n_jobs=8)
```

then access gridsearch.cv_results_ like you are doing, you should get what you are looking for.